# How open python2.7 in spyder, jupyter, qtconsole. from Anaconda Navigator installed with python3? (OS X)

Tags: python, anaconda

Under OS X (10.11.6) I installed the current Python 3.5 version of Anaconda. Anaconda Navigator then works just fine to launch sypder, jupyter,or  qtconsole with python 3.5.2 running.

At the command line I also created a python 2.7 environment (conda create --name python2 python=2.7 anaconda). But now when I open Anaconda Navigator, go to Environments in the left pane, and select my python2 environment, still if I go back to Home and launch  sypder, jupyter, qtconsole, the python version shown is still 3.5.2.

I tried closing Anaconda Navigator, executing "source activate python2" at the command line, and reopening Anaconda Navigator, and again selecting python2 from Environments there. But still  sypder, jupyter, qtconsole open with python 3.5.2.

How do I launch with python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the following commands in the terminal:

1. source activate python2
2. spyder

Spyder will be launched with the python2 environment. With this method you do not use the anaconda navigator, but at least you can use spyder with your python2 environment.